# Can't define method in class

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to create a simple Java class in Eclipse which pulls in a JSON array over an api.  I'm trying to add a method to return a string value, which is creating an error.  It seems that Java doesn't recognize it as a method.

```
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

public class GetSurvey {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int SurveyID   = 2107240;
        String SurveyDate = "2016-01-07";
        String SurveyType;
        String apiurl = "https://restapi.surveygizmo.com/v4/survey/" + SurveyID + "...";
        String Result(){
            return restTemplate.getForObject(apiurl,String.class);
        }
    }
}
```

This is resulting in the following errors:

> Syntax error on token "String", new expected
>
> Result cannot be resolved to a type
>
> Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
>
> Void methods cannot return a value

It seems that it is not recognizing *String Result(){* as a method.  I created the class without defining a method and there's no errors.

Comment: You can't make a method within a method....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address the errors. Other than you can't define a method within a method.

> Syntax error on token "String", new expected

Java syntax is looking for an object declaration like `String s = new String()`.

> Result cannot be resolved to a type

`Result()` is not a defined as a method, so it is trying to be invoked, but can't.

> Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement

`String Result()` expects to be ended by a semi-colon.

> Void methods cannot return a value

Self-explanatory, you can't do any more than `return;` in a `void` method, which `main` is.

---

It would appear you meant to do this

```
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

public class GetSurvey {

   @Autowired
   private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private static String getTemplate(String apiUrl) {
        return restTemplate.getForObject(apiUrl,String.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int SurveyID   = 2107240;
        String SurveyDate = "2016-01-07";
        String SurveyType;
        String apiurl = "https://restapi.surveygizmo.com/v4/survey/" + SurveyID + "...";
        String result = getTemplate(apiurl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define a method inside the main method.

Answer (score 1):

You are nesting methods by defining them inside others, that is not how java works..

move the method

```
String Result(){
    return restTemplate.getForObject(apiurl,String.class);
}
```

out of the `main` method.
and be careful with the scope of the returned val.

Comment: In addition to moving that, restTemplate will need to be defined.